# How to get the count of dataframe rows at 75% or max

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The command below shows some details about the dataframe.

```
df.describe()
```

It gives details about **count, mean, std, min, 25%, ...**

Is there any way to get the count of rows in a dataframe at 75% or 25%?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) to determine the value for the given quantile of the selected column.

  - `.quantile` has the benefit of being able to specify any quantile value (e.g. `30%`)
  - `.describe()` is limited to `[25%, 50%, 75%]`, and it performs unnecessary aggregations.
- Select the specific data using [Boolean selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html), with [`.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and [`.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html)

  - `.ge` is `>=`
  - `.le` is `<=`
  - `.eq` is `==`
- Once you have all the values matching the criteria, use something like `quartile_25.count()` or `len(quartile_25)`, to get determine how many values meet the criteria.
- `col` should be some column name as a `string`

```py
quartile_75 = df[df[col].ge(df[col].quantile(q=.75))]
quartile_25 = df[df[col].le(df[col].quantile(q=.25))]
max_ = df[df[col].eq(df[col].max())]
```